# Books about twin girls that are captured and surgically experimented on

Tags: story-identification, books, horror

I read a young adult book several years ago that was about twin girls that had been captured by either fictional Nazis or it was set in a dystopian world. They were experimented on by being injected with chemicals or hormones or subjected to inhuman surgeries. One sister ends up dying and the other one ends up escaping with other kids. I just can’t remember the title and Google isn’t helping.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You wrote "books" in the title; is that a typo, or was this a series rather than a single book? Also, in roughly which year did you read this and do you recall anything about the cover/s?

Comment: I'd be willing to bet it was based on Nazi Dr Josef Mengele, who experimented on twins.